# How to Implement PieChart with its inputText in #ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the output which I need i tried with Multiple ways Please help me with in detailed code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGTVT.jpg)

This is the output which I need i tried with Multiple ways Please help me with in detailed code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGTVT.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Victory Native's Pie component - https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie#labelposition

```js
<VictoryPie
  data={sampleData}
  labels={({ datum }) => datum.y}
  labelRadius={({ innerRadius }) =>  80 }
  labelPosition={({ index }) => index
    ? "centroid"
    : "startAngle"
  }
/>
```

Comment: This not suporting to react native

Comment: I t work on both web and  React Native - https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native/